# How can I get current bundle's BundleContext instance while using declarative services in karaf 3.0.2

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, karaf, declarative-services, onos

In ONOS on karaf 3.0.2, I wish to get current bundle's BundleContext instance for tracking bundle's status and configuring it. But ONOS uses declarative service, so I cannot use function like `BundleContext.getServiceReference()` to get it.
  Could anyone help me ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can inject the BundleContext in an @Activate method when using DS.

Comment: Do you mean something like this : @Activate public void activate(BundleContext context);